# How to gsub string with any partially matched string

Tags: r, regex

I have my string as:

```
cc <- c("Bacter;httyh;ttyyyt", "Bacteria;hhhdh;hhgt;hhhg", "Bacter;hhhhdj;gg;dd", "Bactr;hhhg;ggj", "Bctg;hhgg;hhj")
```

I would like to replace any text matching `Bact` before first `;`  and replace it with `Bctr`.

I tried:
`gsub("[Bact*]+;", "Bctr", cc)`

So, the result I would like is

`Bctr;httyh;ttyyyt, Bctr;hhhdh;hhgt;hhhg, Bctr;hhhhdj;gg;dd, Bctr;hhhg;ggj, Bctg;hhgg;hhj`

Any suggestion what I am missing here?

Comment: @d.b The fifth string shouldn't have `Bctr`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `sub` and replace from `"Bact"` till the first semi-colon with `"Bctr";`

```
sub("Bact.*?;", "Bctr;", cc)
#[1] "Bctr;httyh;ttyyyt" "Bctr;hhhdh;hhgt;hhhg" "Bctr;hhhhdj;gg;dd"  "Bctr;hhhg;ggj"
```

`*?` is used for lazy matching making it to match as few characters as possible. So here it stops after matching with first semi-colon.

The difference would be clear if we remove `?` from it.

```
sub("Bact.*;", "Bctr;", cc)
#[1] "Bctr;ttyyyt" "Bctr;hhhg"   "Bctr;dd"     "Bctr;ggj"
```

Now it matches till the last semi-colon in `cc`.

Comment: What's the relevance of using `*?` ? I know `?` means zero or one match, but then * means one or more match. Could you please clarify a bit?

Comment: @New_to_R Updated the answer with some explanation.

Answer (score 1):

```
ifelse(grepl("Bact", cc),
       paste0("Bctr", substring(cc,
                                attr(regexpr("Bact.*?;", cc), "match.length"),
                                nchar(cc))),
       cc)
#[1] "Bctr;httyh;ttyyyt"    "Bctr;hhhdh;hhgt;hhhg" "Bctr;hhhhdj;gg;dd"   
#[4] "Bctr;hhhg;ggj"        "Bctg;hhgg;hhj"
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `sub` by matching the `Bact` followed by characters that are not a `:` (`[^;]+`) and replace with "Bctr"

```
sub("Bact[^;]+", "Bctr", cc)
#[1] "Bctr;httyh;ttyyyt" "Bctr;hhhdh;hhgt;hhhg" "Bctr;hhhhdj;gg;dd"  
#[4]  "Bctr;hhhg;ggj"        "Bctg;hhgg;hhj"
```